# I'm not sure when to use "had+pp" or "the past tense"

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-participles

I work from home about twice a week. Yesterday I physically went to work. However, **I hadn't known that** I was supposed to work from home until my senior told me. So, I asked my team manager if I could work from home tomorrow instead.

"I hadn't known that" or "I didn't know that".
I'm not sure which one of these is correct.

Comment: @user405662 doesn't the action "I hadn't known" precede the action "my senior told me"?

Comment: @user405662 I still can't understand. The dictionary says, "The past perfect simple is used to sequence events in the past to show which event happened first." I hadn't known that I was supposed to work from home when my senior told me that I was supposed to work from home. I think the event "I hadn't known" happened first.

Comment: Yesterday I thought that I was supposed to physically go to work.

Comment: This question is probably better answered didactically on ELL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. I hadn't known that
> 2. I didn't know that

The ignorance that you were supposed to work from home happened first.

The realisation when your senior told you that happened next.

You should use 1).

> I **hadn't known** that I was supposed to work from home until my senior told me.

Comment: Thanks for the easy-to-understand explanation. Have a good day.